# How to embed html/js widgets in Nuxt, specifically iFlyChat but broadly applicable

Tags: vue.js, plugins, nuxt.js

I have a couple of plugin widgets that I'd like to integrate into my site but I'm wondering how best to do it to preserve the Nuxt functionality like code-splitting, etc. For example, the code below is for iFlyChat. When I first used the code in my appHeader, it worked, then was intermittent for a while but now doesn't show up at all:

```
<script>
  var iflychat_app_id="xyzappidcode";
  var iflychat_external_cdn_host="cdn.iflychat.com",iflychat_bundle=document.createElement("SCRIPT");iflychat_bundle.src="//"+iflychat_external_cdn_host+"/js/iflychat-v2.min.js?app_id="+iflychat_app_id,iflychat_bundle.async="async",document.body.appendChild(iflychat_bundle);var iflychat_popup=document.createElement("DIV");iflychat_popup.className="iflychat-popup",document.body.appendChild(iflychat_popup);
</script>
```

I've since tried a similar widget for edwid but that didn't show up on the page at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a [nuxt plugin](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/) to init your code on each page.

Fist, create a file `plugins/iflychat.js`:

```js
export default () => {

  console.log("init iflychat plugin");

  var iflychat_app_id = "xyzappidcode";
  var iflychat_external_cdn_host="cdn.iflychat.com",iflychat_bundle=document.createElement("SCRIPT");iflychat_bundle.src="//"+iflychat_external_cdn_host+"/js/iflychat-v2.min.js?app_id="+iflychat_app_id,iflychat_bundle.async="async",document.body.appendChild(iflychat_bundle);var iflychat_popup=document.createElement("DIV");iflychat_popup.className="iflychat-popup",document.body.appendChild(iflychat_popup);

}
```

Then, configure Nuxt.js to import it:

```js
//nuxt.config.js

export default {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~plugins/iflychat.js', mode: 'client' }
  ]
}
```

That's it, you iFlatChat will run on every page view.

Comment: You sir, are a prince among men!